# Java Graphics(Drawing a line)

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm not familiar with the java Graphics, and I want to draw a line over 3 buttons. I found some ways to draw a line, but none of them draws it on top of the buttons.

Here's my GUI class

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
JButton[] buttons;

GUI()
{
    setSize(255, 390);
    setLocation(0, 0);      
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);       
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //TODO add the line    
}
void drawButtons()
{
    buttons=new JButton[9];
    int x=5,y=80;
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
    {
        buttons[i]=new JButton("");
        buttons[i].setSize(70,70);
        buttons[i].setLocation(x,y);
        buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 45));
        buttons[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1,Color.black,Color.black));
        y+=(i%3==2)?75:0;
        x=(i%3==2)?5:x+75;          
        add(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

}

So simply, I want to create a function that creates a line, and gets the location of the line as a parameter. And I want the line to be on top of the buttons. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: All drawing in Swing needs to be done in paintComponent. And the Graphics clipping generally makes it hard to custom paint over multiple components. Recommend checking out JLayer.

Comment: @ControlAltDel paintComponent is the paint function that I have? Well anyway, I can draw a in a layer and add the layer to the frame whenever I want right?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I want the line to be on top of the buttons.

Consider using the [Glass pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) to do the custom drawing, overriding its `paintComponent` method to do the draw on top of the `JFrame`. For example:

```
public class CustomGlassPane extends JPanel{

    public CustomGlassPane(){
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(10, 100, 2000, 100);
    }
}
```

You would then set the Glass pane of the `JFrame`

```
setGlassPane(new CustomGlassPane());
getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
```

As an aside, I would also recommend against using `null` layouts - select the LayoutManager that best suits your layout (and note that you can nest layouts). I would also recommend overriding `paintComponent` rather than `paint` (as your posted code attempts to do).

Comment: `to do the drawing on top of any Components added to the underlying Container` - a GlassPane covers the entire JFrame, not just the Container.

Comment: Okay, I managed to apply this into my code, and used Graphics2D to add a stroke to the line, but it's pretty hard to set the position of the line, do I just have to adjust the numbers in here " g.drawLine(10, 100, 2000, 100);" or is there an easy way to adjust the line position?

Comment: @Ahmed, that is why I made my comment. All the painting is done relative to the frame so you need to translate everything. The two suggestion I gave do the painting relative to the panel which should make the painting easier. You can check out the `SwingUtilities` classes for method that allow you to convert points relative from one component to another.

Comment: @camickr Alright, thank you. However, I will mark this one as the answer :).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html).

As you can see a JPanel will invoke a `paintChildren(...)` method. So you could override this method to paint your line on top of the children of the panel:

```
@Override
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintChildren(g);

    // paint the line here
}
```

Proably the better option is to use a JLayer which is designed specifically for this. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Decorating Components With JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for more information and examples.